Как исправить код, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку значение увеличивалось?
Вот код, если что. Переменную типа counter = 0 я сделал, просто у меня всё работает, но почему-то бот не отвечает.
def send_text(message):
    if message.text.lower() =='кнопка':
        global counter
        counter += 1
        bot.reply_to(message, f"Счетчик увеличен: {counter}")


Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

противоречивые утверждения "у меня всё работает" и "бот не отвечает"

Первое, если функция send_text(message) - это хендлер,
и он зарегистрирован методом add_message_handler,
то добавьте в код функции пару строк:
def send_text(message):
    print("Меня вызвали, и я адекватно реагирую.")
    if message.text.strip().lower() == 'кнопка': # strip() от случайных пробелов.
        print("Условие верно, работаем дальше")

убедитесь, что у Вас действительно функция вызывается и отрабатывает.

Второе, если это вспомогательная функция в которую при вызове из другой
функции в качестве аргумента передаёте message, то вам надо убедиться,
что контекст в котором происходит вызов позволяет использовать переменную bot.
